# How to fetch the data using angular 7 from the server (python) in the real-time to keep UI updated?

Tags: python, angular

How can I synchronise the front-end and back-end to get the data in the real-time than periodically making a request to the back-end API?

I have been using an angular 7.2 framework at the front-end and python as a back-end. I want a technique so that the changes in the back-end and the database can be listened by the front-end and the browser becomes up to date.

Comment: If you have to call api in every second or something like that i will suggest you to use `socket` instead of consuming the api.

Answer (score 0):

Use web sockets :  real time communication between web servers and clients is possible with the help of this protocol.

Answer (score 0):

My hero in this field is WAMP, and the CrossbarIO implementation.

This is not strictly Angular specific, though Angular wrapping exist, but I use Autobahn (Python and JS clients) to achieve this kind of feature.

Have a look at my demo (a "real-time" poll app based on Django) which doc contains all necessary pointers.

https://github.com/alterway/wamp-polls